# Effect of surface roughness on the Magnus force of a rotating cylinder.

Tags: aerodynamics

I need to find the effect of surface roughness on the Magnus force, and I cannot find a equation to describe the flow that has surface roughness in it.

So, it would he helpful if someone could provide the equation, and if possible the source of the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you compute the Magnus force from the known circulation $\Gamma$ via the Kutta-Joukowski formula ($F=\rho\,U_\infty \Gamma L$) there is no effect of surface roughness. Of course, the circulation will depend on surface roughness, so if circulation is unknown you need additional information. [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0376042112000656) has a lot of material on the topic that you might find helpful.

Comment: Please link to abstract pages in the future, rather than PDF files (see v2 edit).

Comment: Is this a policy matter? The link you inserted does not allow readers to view the paper. The link I had provides access to it; I believe this is from the author's home page, and him providing the full paper falls under the fair usage policy of the journal.

Comment: I realise that; the primary concern is that the URL to the abstract page from the journal is more likely to be around than the personal homepage of the author. The best solution is then to include that original link, as well as the name of the paper in full, so it can tracked down if the URL is invalidated, and warn it downloads a PDF rather than going to a webpage.